# Reducing animate() references in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following animation that occurs for an element that goes back and forth across my screen....

```
stage3elf.animate({left: '+=400px'},200).delay(1000)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'-=400px'},100)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'+=400px'},100)  
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'-=400px'},100)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'+=400px'},100)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'-=400px'},100)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'+=400px'},100)  
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'-=400px'},100)
    .animate({top: '+=30px'},100)
    .animate({left:'+=400px'},100, function(){
       console.log('we made it to the end with my elf');    
     });//end stage 4
```

...Is it possible to use a single .animate instance and still do all of the above movements for my elf? or do I need to set a .animate() every time he changes direction?

thanks

Comment: No on single .animate, however you could do it in a loop so that you only write .animate once.

Comment: Or you could use an animation library like Greensock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
stage3elf.animate({
    left: '+=400px'
}, 200).delay(1000);
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    stage3elf.animate({
        top: '+=30px'
    }, 100)
    .animate({
        left: '-=400px'
    }, 100);
}
stage3elf.promise().done(function () {
    console.log('we made it to the end with my elf');
});
```

Comment: Arun, so promise().done acts as a callback?  I never knew that...thanks for sharing this creative approach!

Comment: thanks for the tip on using a for loop to repeat .animate processes.  That part of your demo helped me out.